# Count duplicates cells in column to last row

Tags: vba, excel

I want to count duplicates cells in column to last row, I can count all the rows to last row but cant figure out the duplicate part.

I will continue to look and post back the solution if I find one.

Edit: Changed to the following I get error `Type mismatch"

```
Sub ContactName22()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim count As Long

Sheets(2).Select
lRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row

count = "= SUMPRODUCT((E2 & lRow <>"""")/COUNTIF(E2 & lRow &"""")-(COUNTIF(E2 & lRow &"""")=1))"

MsgBox count

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample macro:

```
Sub CountDuplicates()
    Dim N As Long, cl As Collection
    Dim dCount As Long, V As Variant
    N = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set cl = New Collection
    dCount = 0
    For i = 1 To N
        V = Cells(i, 1).Value
        On Error Resume Next
        If V <> "" Then
            cl.Add V, CStr(V)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Else
                Err.Number = 0
                dCount = dCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "There are " & dCount & " duplicates"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ContactName22()

'Declaring
Dim Sheets(2)As Worksheet
Set Sheets(2)= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets(2)")
Dim x As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long

Sheets(2).Select

lastRow = dbSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = dbSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   For y = 1 to LastColumn 'Looping through the columns until last column

     For x = 2 To lastRow 'Looping through the rows until last row 

            if ...... 'whatever condition that applies in your case  

            Then

             'do something else here

             count = count+1 'counting how many times has found duplicates based on the condition of `if` statment.

             End if

      Next x

 Next y

Cells(lastRow+1,2).Value=count 'assigning the value of the counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Please try to avoid dumping code as an answer. Provide some context, or clarify what you solution is addressing/achieving. Thanks :)